# Is it true that if $f$ is injective, then it must be analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

I'd be interested to know about the connection between injectivity and analyticity of functions. In my humble guess, if $f$ is a real or complex valued function such that it is injective, then it would satisfy the [Cauchy–Riemann equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_function#cite_note-Mark-6), which implies it is analytic. But this is a weaker reason, because I don't know if it's true that "if $f$ is injective then all its derivative exist". Hence, my question. Is it true that if $f$ is injective, then it must be analytic?

Comment: Being invective doesn’t even imply continuity.

Comment: At your level analytic means composition of obviously analytic functions together with : absolutely/uniformly convergent sequences, series and integrals of such analytic functions. Convergence on the real axis isn't enough, we need convergence on some open of $\Bbb{C}$.

Comment: For a **continuous** function $f : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$, that it is injective means $f$ or $-f$ is increasing and continuous, and those functions are exactly the primitives of $L^1_{loc}$ non-negative functions, thus the weak derivative $f'$ exists and is in $L^1$. It doesn't mean $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ exists for all $x$.  It is completely obvious it doesn't extend to functions $\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{C}$ and $\Bbb{C} \to \Bbb{C}$

Answer (score 6):

$f(z)=\overline {z}$ is  a counterexample.